# How can I delete all the databases in my machine without deleting them one by one?

Tags: mysql, database, macos

I want to delete all the databases in my Macbook pro. The number is more than 300 so I can't remove them one by one. How can I delete all the databases without deleting them one by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you can use Linux command line parameters, try:

http://rootedlabs.wordpress.com/2009/10/03/drop-all-databases-in-mysql/